# <select> tag brings up dynamically a different set of input fields depending on selection in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to create a form, first element should be a  tag with a few options and each of them will dynamically bring up a different set of forms depending on what the user chooses. The idea is within the select tag there will be different categories like cars, properties etc.. first user only sees that and when chose, it will bring up a set of input fields that required for that category.

Anyone got an idea what would be the best way to do it in angular?

Comment: use ui-router, and use nested ui-view, fill it with different html/controller depending on selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `ui.router` module, you can populate a DOM element (ui-view) with an HTML template file. On selection of the dropdown, you're telling angular to go to a different "state".

Check out the following plunkr I made: http://plnkr.co/edit/jnKQOvkE4nJinEQ5zhr6?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, I was watching videos about ui-router and ui-view, but still couldnt find the right one and couldnt put the picture together. Sorry still new to angular, but that was exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you again